# robots.txt directory disable 4th and next levels

Tags: seo

Is it possible to disable 3 and more sublevel of directories in robots.txt? For exaple allow /sub1/sub2/sub3 and ceny /sub1/sub2/sub3/sub4/... ? The subx strings are variables.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **SEO** which is off-topic at Stack Overflow. Please read ["Which SEO questions should be closed as non-programming/non-admin?"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382618) to better understand when SEO questions are acceptable to ask here (most are not) and where you might be able to get assistance. Next time, please heed [the warning](https://imgur.com/a/enYwabk) and avoid asking non-programming related SEO related questions here.

Answer (score 0):

Helpful docs: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062596?hl=en

Would recommend:

```
Allow: /sub1/sub2/sub3
Disallow: /sub1/sub2/sub3/*
```

Comment: But subx text is variable some time is man sometime woman sometime color of boots. Thiis is in fact filter fields.

Comment: Your robots.txt must be static it can't be a dynamic page. If there are 4 different values, then you need 4 different expressions or combine them together using regex, but it can't be a function or dynamic on load.